# How can add multiple Options in Selenium with Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to add those options in Python, one for installing an extension and one is for detach browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

service_obj = Service("D:/Python/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
opt.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options = Options()
options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\enach\Downloads\extension_5_8_0_0.crx")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=options, chrome_options = opt)
```

After I run this code, appear this error :

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'chrome_options'
```

I tried to make and multiple options but doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

After many attemps I succed to find an solution.

```
service_obj = Service("D:/Python/Chrome Driver/chromedriver.exe")
options = Options()
options.add_extension(r"C:\Users\enach\Downloads\extension_5_8_0_0.crx")
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj, options=options)
```

You can add how many options do you want, after you define options=Options() and have care to import first `from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`. Good luck and I hope to find useful !

If you have another way to resolve this in Python Selenium I want to hear about it.